# Multiple file upload compatible with Internet Explorer

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, html, file-upload, cross-browser

I would like to have an upload control on an intranet website, which needs to support multiple file upload. Drag and drop is not required, I just want to select a lot of files (in hundreds, possibly) for processing on the server. After the uploads are complete the user will be redirected to another page where he'll be able to process the results.

I'd also like to support other browsers, but IE is the most important as most of the customers use it as per their IT policy and it cannot be changed. Their computers are restricted enough and Silverlight might be the way as it's official Microsoft plugin, compared with Flash.

I would like to have a form with a “Browse” button which allows the user to pick files, then the file names are added to a list and “Upload” button that starts the upload to a server side code that saves the file somewhere and redirects the user to the next page.

I think that I should use Silverlight for IE7/8/9 and HTML5 for Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera (and IE10, eventually). That would mean coding two separate (html5+silverlight) front-ends and one common back-end on the server.

*I know* that Telerik has [something exactly like this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/async/multiplefileselection/defaultcs.aspx) and works, but it's too expensive as I need only one control of their library.

Is there something open-source that works this way? Or is there a better and simpler way to support IE and HTML5 file-compliant browsers?

Comment: So Flash is not an option at all?

Comment: silverlight will be as much a hassle for them to install than for them to roll out firefox on all the computers.

Comment: they won't change browsers, I'm sure of it. But I'm starting to think that maybe the best option would be to say that on IE we'll just support single file upload for the time being...

Comment: that's enterprise for you, saving you work.

Comment: Google is awesome - just saying: http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'm using exactly that control, but I also needed to code a HTML5 upload control similar to that, using the same backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight will work in all the browsers, so that's the way to go (right now).  After IE 10 comes out, then HTML-5 might be a better choice.

Comment: but there's no need to force users of HTML5 multi-file-upload compliant browsers to use Silverlight plugin, as the problem (ability to pick multiple files for upload) exists only in IE < 10.

Answer (score 2):

flash is the solution, as flash 7 was shipped by default in windows xp.

but in the end something's got to give, it professionals will have to say no to corporations that have operating systems older than 10 years.

Comment: and will something like uploadify work on flash shipped by default in windows xp?

Comment: as long as they don't contain any more advanced feature, you will have to experiment with a copy of xp

Answer (score 0):

Look at this jquery plugin http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: that doesn't allow selecting more than 1 file in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit older, but have you looked at [pulpload](http://www.plupload.com/) or even [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)? Both provide HTML5 and Flash versions.

Pulpload is somewhat more versatile, it seems, but I have implemented uploadify a few times, and the docs are ... good enough (I think version 3 of uploadify is much better, but I don't have experience implementing it, yet).

Comment: I have, but Flash was not an option.